# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 freezes after I build the solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Whenever I am building a solution, vs2013 is freezing. I do not know why? I have uninstall it and re-install it I am still having the same problem. It is hanging, can someone tell me a solution for this problem. It is running fine since 5 months, all of a sudden i am having this problem.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the latest service packs. I had all sorts of issues until I installed them.

Comment: How to install them?

Comment: You need to search for them first, and then download them. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx

Comment: No still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Is the solution very large with lots of projects?

Try disabling code optimization.
You haven't specified a language, but in C++ it is in Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> Set Optimization to False

Comment: When i have re-install I am running it with a cout<<"Hello world"<<endl it is still freezing

Comment: Running a program and building a solution are two very different things. When is VS freezing?

Comment: when building the program it is freezing